# Register class with params in Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I try register inteface `IDataService` and `RegisterLawyers` with Simple Injector but in the controller throw exeption:

> The constructor of type RegisterLawyer contains parameter 'email' of type String, which can not be used for constructor injection. Parameter name: TImplementation.

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Register<IDataService, RegisterLawyer>(Lifestyle.Transient);

container.Verify();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

public class RegisterLawyer : IDataService
{
    private string _email;
    private string _personalNumber;
    private string _egn;

    public RegisterLawyer(string email, string personalNumber, string egn)
    {
        this._email = email;
        this._egn = egn;
        this._personalNumber = personalNumber;           
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-parameter-injection-behavior)

Comment: The values are some kind of configuration values? Or do these values change possible every request?

Comment: It seems that these values are runtime values: [change your design](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).